Can I use the NestJS Prop without type with Swc compiler?
I'm trying to migrate to swc compiler on NestJS. But I faced compiling typescript issues. For example, I have a model named User:
@Schema({timestamps: true})
export class User {
  @ApiProperty({example: 'john@doe.com', description: 'Email', type: String})
  @Prop({required: false, type: String})
  email: string;

  @ApiProperty({example: '5555555555', description: 'Phone number'})
  @Prop({required: false})
  phone: string;

  @ApiProperty({example: 'asd123456', description: 'Password'})
  @Prop({required: true})
  password: string;
}

I'm trying to compile this model by using swc src -d dist command, it throws this error:
throw new errors_1.CannotDetermineTypeError((_a = target.constructor) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.name, propertyKey);
                ^

CannotDetermineTypeError: Cannot determine a type for the "User.phone" field (union/intersection/ambiguous type was used). Make sure your property is decorated with a "@Prop({ type: TYPE_HERE })" decorator.

It was not a problem to not to use type field in the @Prop decorator with the tsc. It automatically determines the types with some exceptions. But swc forces me to define type. I want to use the swc for its speed of compile.
Let me give my configuration files as well:
.swcrc:
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/swcrc",
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "module": {
    "type": "commonjs"
  },
  "jsc": {
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript",
      "decorators": true,
      "dynamicImport": true
    },
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "minify": false
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "isolatedModules": false
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}

nest-cli.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "builder": "swc"
  },
  "questions": [
    {
      "name": "transport",
      "type": "list",
      "message": "What transport layer do you use?",
      "choices": [
        {
          "name": "REST API",
          "value": "rest"
        },
        {
          "name": "GraphQL",
          "value": "graphql"
        }
      ],
      "default": "rest"
    },
    {
      "name": "generateCrud",
      "type": "confirm",
      "message": "Would you like to generate CRUD entry points?",
      "default": true
    }
  ]
}

Is there any way to use swc to compile my codes without defining the types of the Props?
Thanks.
